# ElasticSearch 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: elasticsearch

I am learning ElasticSearch in conjunction with Laravel and Docker. Faced the same problem

```
504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.19.6
```

My code

```
public function esSearch() {

    $client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['172.20.0.1:9200'])->build();

    $params = [
        'index' => 'my_index',
        'id' => 'my_id',
        'body' => ['testField' => 'abc']
    ];

    $result = $client->index($params);

    var_dump($result);
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You're using the `index` operation but you seem to be sending a payload for an update. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I just follow the examples of this package documentation https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php

Comment: Which one exactly?

Comment: https://youtu.be/dCRiIMfuW4Y?t=1769

Comment: If you look at the body on the "Single document indexing" slide, it's different than yours. The body you use is the one you can find on the "Updating document" slide a bit further

Comment: Yes, I tried to reproduce another example from the video tutorial. The code in the question has been updated.

Comment: Well, `504 Gateway Time-out` usually means that your client cannot access the cluster at 172.20.0.1. Since it's not in the public IP address range, are you able to ping it?

Comment: nginx  cant access to elasticsearch  ... check  accesable